# Why does my QML ListView overlap my Text in a Column positioner?

Tags: qml

A Column positioner is supposed to position its children in a column. But when one of the children is a ListView, I find it overlaps the other children.

When the children are just Text's there's no overlapping and everything is fine.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Column {
        Text {
            text: "Hello World"
        }

// This works - appears under "Hello World"
        Text {
            text: "Hi Again"
        }

// This doesn't - overlaps "Hello World" and "Hi Again"
        ListModel {
            id: theModel
            ListElement { display: "one" }
            ListElement { display: "two" }
            ListElement { display: "three" }
        }
        ListView {
            height:100
            model: theModel
            delegate: Text {
                text: display
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result: Listview appears under "Hi Again"
Actual result: ListView overlaps "Hello World" and "Hi Again"

I often come a cropper with overlapping items in QML. Am I missing something fundamental that someone can explain to me? I'm having trouble finding a good reference book for QML positioning.

Comment: Using a `Repeater` instead of a `ListView` here might better suit you if you don't want the scrolling behaviour of the `ListView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Column` (and other positioners for that matter) will not position items that are deemed invisible, the definition being `height` and `width` above zero and `visible = false`. This means you can easily solve it by anchoring the `ListView` to the left and right of it's parent:

```
    ListView {
        height:100
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right

        Component.onCompleted: console.log(implicitHeight, implicitWidth)
        model: theModel
        delegate: Text {
            text: display
        }
    }
```